# Why does std::tr1::function work with Objective-C Blocks?

Tags: c++, objective-c++, objective-c-blocks

I was pretty surprised when I found that the following code actually works:

```
std::vector<int> list /*= ...*/;
std::tr1::function<void(int)> func = ^(int i) {
  return i + 1;
};

std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), func);
```

Seems like `std::tr1::function` is capable of being constructed from an Objective-C block, but I'm not sure quite how, since (last I checked), its implementation doesn't specifically handle blocks. Is it somehow implicitly sucking out the underlying function pointer? Also, is this behavior undefined and likely to change?

Comment: From a C++ perspective, your std::function holds a pointer to anything looking like `void f(int)`. If that is what a block looks like, it will work (otherwise not).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update: I was wrong, here's why it really works**

`std::tr1::function`'s template parameter simply defines the *signature* of the resulting function object, not the type it actually wraps. Thus, the wrapped object only needs to offer an `operator()` with matching signature. Block references, like function pointers, have such an `operator()` implicitly (obviously, so you can call them).

**Old, incorrect answer (so the comments make sense)**

I strongly suspect it works because the block doesn't capture any variables from the surrounding scope. In that case, there is no state to maintain, so a block reference can be represented as a bare function pointer. If we change the code to

```
std::vector<int> list /*= ...*/;
int counter = 0;
std::tr1::function<void(int)> func = ^(int i) {
  counter++;
  return i + counter;
};

std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), func);
```

it should fail to compile, as the block must carry the captured value of `counter` around with it. (unless of course the implementation of `std::tr1::function` *has* been specifically updated to support blocks)

Comment: `std(::tr1)::function` totally doesn't care what it should invoke, as long as the signature works. You should get something like a functor from that Objective-C block, and a `std(::tr1)::function` can invoke a function perfectly fine. I take that Objective-C blocks work similar to C++0x lambdas, and `std(::tr1)::function`s can operate on lambdas just fine, because they're basically functors. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although you can treat blocks as Objective-C objects and Objective-C has a lot of support for blocks, blocks aren't limited to Objective-C. You can also use blocks in C and C++. See [this article](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/) for more information.